# Why my MailHog doesn't integrate with PHP?

Tags: php, docker, email, homebrew, mailhog

I am setting up the dev environment on the M1 MBP. The PHP and NGINX are installed with the HomeBrew directly on the machine. The ElasticSearch and MailHog - with the Docker.

I am struggling to see the email in the MailHog web interface after I send one through from the PHP file. The project is working and my local PHP and NGINX communicates with the Dockerised ElasticSearch well, so I am sure MailHog is "installed" properly; I see the interface on my web on port 8025 as well.

I've played around with the php.ini file (`/opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/php.ini`). I've double checked that ini file is the one that is used for the project (verified it with changing `memory_limit` value. I've updated the Postfix (`/etc/postfix/main.cf`) configuration with the following configuration too:

```
# For MailHog
myhostname = localhost
relayhost = [localhost]:1025
```

...and reloaded it like this `sudo postfix reload`.

My `/etc/hosts` file has this line: `127.0.0.1 l.month db elasticsearch mail`; and pinging them all works too.

When I keep the php.ini file line (containing the `sendmail_path`) commented out the `mail` function in PHP script works; but the email is sent directly to my real email address, not the MailHog. If I uncomment it and set it to `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -S mail:1025` then the `mail` function from PHP is returning `false`. I don't understand why, since this value is advised to be used from [this source](https://kinsta.com/blog/mailhog/). However if I use the `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` PHP again works, but the MailHog doesn't intercept anything. I've double checked that the real path for the `sendmail` is `/usr/sbin/sendmail` by executing the command `which sendmail`.

I also played around with the `SMTP` value and the `smtp_port` (in same ini file); I changed values from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and `mail`; and the 25 to 1025 respectively. I didn't forget to restart my PHP service after each change either.

Furthermore, I experimented with the postfix configuration values by changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and `mail` (as well as reloading it) as well; no luck.

To make sure I tried all of it, I also logged out and logged in to my account to make sure the changes take place; no luck again.

I assume that I do not need the `mhsendmail` file on my local if I have the docket container running, so I never installed it, hoping it is in the docker container; otherwise, then what's the point of the container after all? If I am wrong with my assumption, please let me know.

Regarding logs, no errors are shown; only this message:

```
[05-Aug-2022 13:11:24 UTC] mail() on [/Users/[path_here]]src/pub/mail.php:3]: To: my@email.com -- Headers:  -- Subject: Test Subject
```

FireWall is disabled on the machine.

Please help me solve my problem so that I could see the email send from the PHP in the MailHog web interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Found because decided to go with the workaround - downloaded the MailHog with the HomeBrew instead of using Docker. But it didn't work! I realised I forgot to download the `mhsendmail` since I am using the local MailHog.

Then it hit me! I googled this: `do i need to install mhsendmail if I use docker`. And I got the answer: `No, mhsendmail is not included in the mailhog/mailhog docker container. You will need to download mhsendmail (by either curl or go get) in the container that you are planning to send email from.`

So apparently I was wrong to assume that MailHog comes with the `mhsendmail` binary.

It started to work when I downloaded one and updated the postfix config file to:

```
myhostname = localhost
relayhost = [127.0.0.1]:1025
```

I didn't even need to touch the php.ini! The `sendmail` line can stay commented out!

I hope this answer helps others as well!